# Zeno's Monoid: Has anyone got a reference for this?

Tags: reference-request, examples-counterexamples, monoid, ordered-fields

Let F be an ordered field. Let k be a positive element of F. Define a binary operator * on F:

x*y = x+y - xy/k

Then I claim ([0,k],*,0) is a commutative monoid with k as an absorbing element.

Moreover if you have an element a, such that 0 < a < k,
then

a < a * a < a * a * a < ....< a^n < a^{n+1} < ...... < k.

This is why I think of it as "Zeno's Monoid". However when I search for examples of monoids, I never find it. Does anybody know of a reference?

Comment: Not sure I follow. F could be the rational numbers, or the reals (and other fields). So surely you can't have the all ordered monoids are isomorphic.

Comment: Ah okay. I see your point. You mean you might as well pick the identity to be k. As it happens I found this from a practical application where k will always be a whole number greater than 1.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "your operation goes opposite the order on F". I did not change the ordering in my construction.

Comment: I am not clear on why changing the ordering is interesting. I worked out some more properties of this structure and put them in a pdf. Maybe you are asking how unique those properties in some sense?

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) when typing math formulas. Also $x+y - xy/k$ is ambiguous. Do you mean $(x+y - xy)/k$ or $x+y - (xy/k)$ ?